# How can I get GeoKettle (or any other Java based ETL) to run on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: mac, spatial-etl

Has anyone managed to get GeoKettle or Spatial extension for Talend running on MacOS Sierra? If so, how did you do it?

These packages have not been updated since 2015 and Apple has more or less discontinued support for Java in Sierra. I have installed both Oracles and Apples versions of Java, but to no avail.

I am looking for a spatial ETL tool (extract, transform, load) that is up to date and won´t break the bank, or my good mood. Most of what we need it for is pretty simple stuff like renaming, moving around and processing data in the tables and so on. We are designers and not software engineers, so writing our own scripts is to time consuming.

(Edited for clarity per request)

Comment: Look into GDAL, it might do what you need

Comment: If not likely to produce opinions (like what qualifies as up to date) then this also appears to be seeking input about multiple issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, HALE is in active development. The latest release is just 2 months old at the time of writing. So that would quality as "up to date" in my book.

Comment: As the question was edited, this answer is not an answer anymore...